# Webpack gives $ is not defined or jQuery is not defined error in console

Tags: javascript, webpack

Hey guys I tried everything and I am ready to burst out in shame and I am tired of getting this same error over and over for the past 4 hours. I'm just going to copy and paste the console so we can see how bad it is:

```
Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery
    at bootstrap.min.js:6
(anonymous) @ bootstrap.min.js:6
etw.js:4 Fri Feb 10 2017
etw.js:125 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    at LFDTrack (etw.js:125)
    at Object.LFD_Search (etw.js:244)
    at User.lfd_search (etw.js:25)
    at etw.js:250
LFDTrack @ etw.js:125
LFD_Search @ etw.js:244
User.lfd_search @ etw.js:25
(anonymous) @ etw.js:250
jBox.min.js:2 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
    at jBox.min.js:2
(anonymous) @ jBox.min.js:2
jquery.datetimepicker.full.min.js:1Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
    at jquery.datetimepicker.full.min.js:1
    at jquery.datetimepicker.full.min.js:1
(anonymous) @ jquery.datetimepicker.full.min.js:1
(anonymous) @ jquery.datetimepicker.full.min.js:1
owl.carousel.js:1517 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
    at owl.carousel.js:1517
(anonymous) @ owl.carousel.js:1517
(index):539 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    at (index):539
(anonymous) @ (index):539
featherlight.min.js:8 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
    at featherlight.min.js:8
(anonymous) @ featherlight.min.js:8
jquery.datetimepicker.full.min.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
    at jquery.datetimepicker.full.min.js:1
    at jquery.datetimepicker.full.min.js:1
(anonymous) @ jquery.datetimepicker.full.min.js:1
(anonymous) @ jquery.datetimepicker.full.min.js:1
pagecrossfade-min.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
    at pagecrossfade-min.js:1
```

Here is my main.js file, the entry:

```
"use strict";

import $ from 'jquery';
import jQuery from 'jquery';
window.$ = jQuery;
import moment from 'moment';
import _ from 'lodash';
import math from 'mathjs';
//import jBox from 'jbox';
```

And here is my webpack.config.js
I tried switchign everything around. a.k.a taking out the loaders part and leaving the plugins part there, or taking out the imports in the main.js and leaving only the stuff in the webpack.config.js for jquery, etc. Nothing works. I feel like I am the only person in the web who still has this error because everyone else has gotten it fixed so I have no where to look on google search anymore.(p.s. I dont know if this does anything but the datetime picker and other scripts  in the console are script tags pointing to cdn's in the html file)

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
    entry: './main.js',
    output: { path: __dirname, filename: 'bundle.js' },
    watch: true,
    plugins: [
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            $: "jquery",
            jQuery: "jquery",
            "window.jQuery": "jquery"
        })
    ],
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /[\/\\]node_modules[\/\\]some-module[\/\\]index\.js$/,
                loader: "imports?this=>window"
            },
            {
                test: /[\/\\]node_modules[\/\\]some-module[\/\\]index\.js$/,
                loader: "imports?define=>false"
            }
    ]
    }
}
```

Comment: What does you html look like? I would suspect you are putting your JavaScript bundle after bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

I was having this same problem.

My error was:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
    at eval (featherlight.min.js?60bc:8)
    at Object../node_modules/featherlight/release/featherlight.min.js
```

Your question actually provided the hint that **solved** it for me.

```
const $ = require("jquery");
window.jQuery = $;    //When I added this line, it worked!
require('featherlight');
```